# nleqslv, R, nonlinear equation system

Tags: r, equation-solving

I have the following nonlinear equation system:

```
r1*r2*(0.25*0.6061-0.5)+r1+(0.25*r2) = 0.6061
r1*r2*(0.25*0.6429-0.5)+r1+(0.25*r2) = 0.6429
```

I need to find the `r1` and `r2`. Their solution should be equal to:

```
r1 = 0.5754
r2 = 0.6201
```

which resulted from Fortran.
I don't know how can I find the solutions using `nleqslv` package.

I will appreciate it if anybody can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure of those solutions? I am getting values close to `c(r1, r2) == c(1, 4)`.

Comment: The solution obtained using NAG (C05PBF) which is Fortran program. By the way, I couldn't understand how you performed the Jacobian

Comment: The solutions you gave are not correct.. Try solving the second equation with the solutions you have.. They do not work

Answer (score 2):

The way to use `nleqslv` would be to define a function returning a 2-dim vector, just like `c(r1, r2)`.
That function takes a 2-dim argument `x`. I have replaced `r1` and `r2` by `x[1]` and `x[2]`, respectively.
I have also replaced your 1st equation constant `(0.25*0.6061-0.5)` by its value, `-0.348475`. And in the 2nd equation, `(0.25*0.6429-0.5)` by `-0.339275`.
As for the initial values, I have first tried `c(0, 0)` but it didn't work. If you run the code below with initial values `c(0.5, 0.5)` you will get the same solution, within floating point precision.

```
fn <- function(x){
    c(-0.348475*x[1]*x[2] + x[1] + 0.25*x[2] - 0.6061,
      -0.339275*x[1]*x[2] + x[1] + 0.25*x[2] - 0.6429)
}

nleqslv(c(1, 1), fn)
#$`x`
#[1] 1.000000 3.999999
#
#$fvec
#[1] 4.773959e-14 4.607426e-14
#
#$termcd
#[1] 1
#
#$message
#[1] "Function criterion near zero"
#
#$scalex
#[1] 1 1
#
#$nfcnt
#[1] 2
#
#$njcnt
#[1] 1
#
#$iter
#[1] 2
```

Note that `$fvec` is near zero, and that `$termcd` is `1`. This means that the algorithm converged. To have just the solution you can run

```
sol <- nleqslv(c(1, 1), fn)
sol$x
#[1] 1.000000 3.999999
```

If you can compute the jacobian, and in this case it is even very easy, the algorithm is more accurate.

```
jacfn <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    Df <- matrix(numeric(n*n), n, n)
    Df[1,1] <- -0.348475*x[2] + 1
    Df[1,2] <- -0.348475*x[1] + 0.25
    Df[2,1] <- -0.339275*x[2] + 1
    Df[2,2] <- -0.339275*x[1] + 0.25

    Df
}

sol2 <- nleqslv(c(1, 1), fn, jac = jacfn)
sol2$x
#[1] 1 4
```

The solution is the same.

Comment: The solution obtained using NAG (C05PBF) which is Fortran program. By the way, I couldn't understand how you performed the Jacobian.

Comment: @AmirAliakbari The Jacobian is simple, create a matrix of dimension equal to `length(x)`, then fill it with the partial derivatives of the objective function. As for your solution, try it in the equation. `fn(c(r1, r2))` outputs `[1] -1.281055e-05 -3.353020e-02`, far from zero.